# Applying transformation of `GatherBy` to a different list

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have `listA` and `listB` of the same size. I'm doing `GatherBy` on `listA`, which rearranges that list. What is an elegant way to apply identical rearrangement to `listB`?

For example

```
listA = {1, 2, 3};
listB = {a, b, c};
listA1 = GatherBy[{1, 2, 3}, OddQ];
```

`listB1` should become `{{a, c}, {b}}`

**Update**
Thanks for interesting ideas, I eventually ended up doing something similar to belisarius. This reminds me of Python's "decorate-sort-undecorate" pattern

```
decorated = Thread[{listA, listB}];
grouped = GatherBy[decorated, OddQ[First[#]] &];
listB1 = Map[Last, grouped, {2}]
```

Comment: For really large lists, `grouped[[All, All, -1]]` may be faster or much faster than using `Map` (not sure if this is relevant for your case)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, <s>first</s> second try:

(Warning Warning ... "elegance" is an utterly subjective concept)

```
gBoth[lslave_, lmaster_, f_] := 
                 {Part[#, All, All, 1], Part[#, All, All, 2]} &@ 
                 GatherBy[Transpose[{lslave, lmaster}], f[#[[2]]] &]

lmaster = {1, 2, 3};
lslave = {a, b, c};  

{lslave1, lmaster1} = gBoth[lslave, lmaster, OddQ]
```

Out

```
{{{a, c}, {b}}, {{1, 3}, {2}}}
```

**Edit**

Note that for this code to run you must have

```
 Dimensions[lslave][[1;;Length[Dimensions@lmaster]]] == Dimensions@lmaster
```

but the deeper internal structure of both lists could be different. For example:

```
lmaster = {{1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 4}};
lslave = {{{a}, {b}, {c}}, {{a}, {b}, {c}}};

{lslave1, lmaster1} = gBoth[lslave, lmaster, #[[1]] < 3 &]
```

Out

```
{{{{{a}, {b}, {c}}, {{a}, {b}, {c}}}}, {{{1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 4}}}}
```

HTH!

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
Map[listB[[#]] &, listA1 /. Dispatch@Thread[listA -> Range[Length[listA]]]]
```

Edit : It actually came to my mind that this solution will have problems if `listA` has repeated elements.Besides, it uses the specialized knowledge that the resulting list is of constant depth 2. 
Here is a more general (admittedly, ugly) version, which does not care what is the resulting list structure, or whether the original list did have repeated elements :

```
Clear[rearrangeAs];
rearrangeAs[source_List, transformed_List, target_List] := 
  Module[{f, count, symbs = Table[Unique[], {Length[source]}]}, 
    count[_] = 0;
    f[x_, _] := x;
    MapThread[With[{cnt = ++count[#1]}, f[#1, cnt] := #2] &, {source, symbs}];
    Clear[count];
    count[_] = 0;
    Replace[transformed, x_ :> f[x, ++count[x]], {0, Infinity}] /. 
       Dispatch[Thread[symbs -> target]]]
```

For example,

```
In[94] := rearrangeAs[listA, listA1, listB]

Out[94] = {{a, c}, {b}}
```

I did not test, but this function should also work when the transformed list does not have a regular structure, but is some general tree

Answer (score 1):

You essentially want:

```
Map[listB[[#]] &, listA1]
```

Since ListB[[{1,3,5}]] for example gives a list of the first, third, and fifth elements of ListB.

So this a very simple version of the function:

```
example[listA_, listB_, ordering_] := 
 Map[listB[[#]] &, GatherBy[listA, ordering]]
```

Its important to note that if a number is duplicated in ListA then it won't appear because of the behavior of GatherBy:

```
example[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 3, 5}, {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h}, OddQ]

{{a, c, e, c, e}, {b, d, f}}
```

Comment: example[{{1, 3}, {2, 3, 4}, {1, 2}}, {a, b, c}, Length] seems not working

Comment: Yeah my function is really really simple for simple cases. ListA has to be Range[Length[listB]] so it has limited useability. Sorry, should have mentioned.