# Mathematica: reconstruct an arbitrary nested list after Flatten

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

What is the simplest way to map an arbitrarily funky nested list `expr` to a function `unflatten` so that `expr==unflatten@@Flatten@expr`?

**Motivation:**
`Compile` can only handle full arrays (something I just learned -- but not from the error message), so the idea is to use `unflatten` together with a compiled version of the flattened expression:

```
fPrivate=Compile[{x,y},Evaluate@Flatten@expr];
f[x_?NumericQ,y_?NumericQ]:=unflatten@@fPrivate[x,y]
```

**Example of a solution to a less general problem:**
What I actually need to do is to calculate all the derivatives for a given multivariate function up to some order. For this case, I hack my way along like so:

```
expr=Table[D[x^2 y+y^3,{{x,y},k}],{k,0,2}];
unflatten=Module[{f,x,y,a,b,sslot,tt},
  tt=Table[D[f[x,y],{{x,y},k}],{k,0,2}] /. 
    {Derivative[a_,b_][_][__]-> x[a,b], f[__]-> x[0,0]};
  (Evaluate[tt/.MapIndexed[#1->sslot[#2[[1]]]&, 
            Flatten[tt]]/. sslot-> Slot]&) ] 

Out[1]= {x^2 y + y^3, {2 x y, x^2 + 3 y^2}, {{2 y, 2 x}, {2 x, 6 y}}}
Out[2]= {#1, {#2, #3}, {{#4, #5}, {#5, #7}}} &
```

This works, but it is neither elegant nor general.

**Edit:** Here is the "job security" version of the solution provided by aaz:

```
makeUnflatten[expr_List]:=Module[{i=1},
    Function@Evaluate@ReplaceAll[
        If[ListQ[#1],Map[#0,#1],i++]&@expr,
        i_Integer-> Slot[i]]]
```

It works a charm:

```
In[2]= makeUnflatten[expr]
Out[2]= {#1,{#2,#3},{{#4,#5},{#6,#7}}}&
```

Comment: I didn't test it, but modification of Leonid Shifrin's `rearrangeAs` might work http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4811082/applying-transformation-of-gatherby-to-a-different-list/4811794#4811794

Comment: Thanks, Yaroslav: That certainly looks related -- but it's a bit hard to grok :). I ended up doing something myself which I'll post if nobody bites...  Same story always: 1) solve problem for you specific case, 2) realize that a more general solution could be fun, 3) to avoid wasting time on tangent, post it on SO for others to do your tangential work, 4) do it yourself as well. Sigh

Comment: This question seems related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3807976/inverse-of-flatten-in-mathematica

Comment: @Yaroslav  I adjusted my version to this question, and ended up with something very similar to the solution by @aaz, but the latter is simpler and more elegant.

Comment: @dbjohn: Thanks. The question you mention only deals with "full arrays" -- for which, incidentally, there would be no need for this hack as Compile handles those just fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You obviously need to save some information about list structure, because `Flatten[{a,{b,c}}]==Flatten[{{a,b},c}]`.

If `ArrayQ[expr]`, then the list structure is given by `Dimensions[expr]` and you can reconstruct it with `Partition`. E.g.

```
expr = {{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}};
dimensions = Dimensions[expr]

  {2,3}

unflatten = Fold[Partition, #1, Reverse[Drop[dimensions, 1]]]&;
expr == unflatten @ Flatten[expr]
```

(The `Partition` man page actually has a similar example called `unflatten`.)

---

If `expr` is not an array, you can try this:

```
expr = {a, {b, c}};
indexes = Module[{i=0}, If[ListQ[#1], Map[#0, #1], ++i]& @expr]

  {1, {2, 3}}

slots = indexes /. {i_Integer -> Slot[i]}

  {#1, {#2, #3}}

unflatten = Function[Release[slots]]

  {#1, {#2, #3}} &

expr == unflatten @@ Flatten[expr]
```

Comment: Yes, I have used the first one a couple of times, but the second version is what I need -- and very nicely done! Using Slot[0] for anonymous recursion never occurred to me :) Thanks.

Comment: I just found out about `Slot[0]` while writing this; it's under _Neat Examples_, obviously :)

Comment: Is `Release` documented? Can anyone guide me to some information? I am using Mma 7 (M. Trott, in 'Programming' says it is undocumented, but gives no further information, as far as I can see).

Comment: @TomD - [Sort of](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Release.html). Here it works the same as `Evaluate`.

Comment: @TomD, @aaz: When I fist saw aaz's solution I thought Release was some cool function I had somehow missed. But after looking it up I actually used Evaluate in my summary update :)

Comment: @Janus, @TomD – I always naturally thought that "release" was the antonym of "hold". Guess that's why it's deprecated for two decades, but not yet removed.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you are trying to do with Compile. It is used when you want to evaluate procedural or functional expressions very quickly on numerical values, so I don't think it is going to help here. If repeated calculations of D[f,...] are impeding your performance, you can precompute and store them with something like
`Table[d[k]=D[f,{{x,y},k}],{k,0,kk}];`

Then just call d[k] to get the kth derivative.

Comment: Thanks. I quite agree that I wouldn't need compile for the example case -- but I don't think anyone would thank me for posting the actual expression I'm working with :) My question is the first sentence, everything else is background.

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to update the excellent solutions by aaz and Janus.  It seems that, at least in Mathematica 9.0.1.0 on Mac OSX, the assignment (see aaz's solution)

```
{i_Integer -> Slot[i]}
```

fails.  If, however, we use

```
{i_Integer :> Slot[i]}
```

instead, we succeed.  The same holds, of course, for the `ReplaceAll` call in Janus's "job security" version.

For good measure, I include my own function.

```
unflatten[ex_List, exOriginal_List] := 
  Module[
   {indexes, slots, unflat},
   indexes = 
     Module[
       {i = 0}, 
       If[ListQ[#1], Map[#0, #1], ++i] &@exOriginal
       ];
   slots = indexes /. {i_Integer :> Slot[i]};
   unflat = Function[Release[slots]];
   unflat @@ ex
   ];

(* example *)
expr = {a, {b, c}};
expr // Flatten // unflatten[#, expr] &
```

It might seem a little like a cheat to use the original expression in the function, but as aaz points out, we need *some* information from the original expression.  While you don't need it *all*, in order to have a *single* function that can `unflatten`, all is necessary.

My application is similar to Janus's: I am parallelizing calls to `Simplify` for a tensor.  Using `ParallelTable` I can significantly improve performance, but I wreck the tensor structure in the process.  This gives me a quick way to reconstruct my original tensor, simplified.

Comment: The original is still working fine for me in v9. The purpose of `makeUnflatten` is exactly to store the information about the structure of `expr` into an anonymous unpack function -- so there is no need to keep the original expression around.